# Plot vertical gridlines for prime values of `x`

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

I want to create a plot with vertical gridlines for prime `x`, and no gridlines otherwise. I can do it manually:

```
Plot[PrimePi[x], {x, 0, 100}, GridLines -> 
{{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 
 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}, None}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

But I can't find a way of using (say) `PrimeQ` to automate the process; I have to enter each prime value by hand.

I suspect there is an answer on MSE already, but I have searched and failed to find it.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bkarpuz's suggestion works perfectly:

```
With[{q = 100},
          Plot[PrimePi[x], {x, 0, q},
                   GridLines -> {Table[Prime[n], {n, PrimePi[q]}], None},
                    PlotPoints -> q]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I added a function definition and new figures. I do not know why they are listed above your answer.

Comment: @Gommaire, that is because answers are sorted by vote counts by default. Try clicking on the "active" tab above the answers.

Answer (score 4):

I am a novice, but this does not seem too difficult.
Let us use variable q instead of the integer 100.
Then:

```
q = 100;
Plot[PrimePi[x], {x, 0, q}, GridLines -> {Table[Prime[n], {n, PrimePi[q]}], None},
     PlotPoints -> q]
```

[image: plot of prime-counting function]

Comment: I have marked this as answered, but I do have one further question. Is there a way of doing this using `Replace` instead of assigning a value to `q` which must then be cancelled before any further work is carried out? Putting `/. q -> 20` on the end works, but produces annoying error messages.

Comment: Maybe you can use `With`

Comment: That works. Do you want to add it as an answer and I'll mark it up? Thanks, BTW :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using `With` (as suggested by bkarpuz) we can define an own function plotPrimes[x_] where the argument x is the integer to be entered in PrimePi[]. Apparently, Richard Burke-Ward already did so.

If we wish to experiment with another kind of plot where we put the primes as ticks on the X-axis, we may define an alternative function. We put the prime values alternately on two X-axes to enhance readability. The color and size of the font may be adjusted in Directive[Black,9].

```
plotPrimesAlt[z_Integer] :=

 With[{q = z}, DiscretePlot[PrimePi[x], {x, 0, q},
   GridLines -> {Table[Prime[n], {n, PrimePi[q]}], None},
   FrameTicks -> 
    {
     {Range[0, q], Range[0, q]},
     {Table[Prime[n], {n, PrimePi[q]}][[1 ;; ;; 2]], 
      Table[Prime[n], {n, PrimePi[q]}][[2 ;; ;; 2]]}
     },
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 9], PlotLegends -> None,
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ExtentSize -> Right, ImageSize -> Large]]
```

Let us use the alternative function with x=100 as in the original question:

```
plotPrimesAlt[100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree that bkarpuz's suggestion works perfectly. However, you have to assign a value to q and repeat the lines for plotting. If you first define a function:

```
plotPrimes[z_Integer] :=
 With[{q = z}, Plot[PrimePi[x], {x, 0, q},
   GridLines -> {Table[Prime[n], {n, PrimePi[q]}], None},
   PlotPoints -> q]]
```

, then you can use this function repeatedly in further work without having to repeat Plot[.....]. May be I am mistaken, but I suppose you may wish to do something like:

```
plotPrimes[13]
```

[image]

And further on, you may wish to show

```
plotPrimes[37]
```

[image]

Comment: If it is not an entirely new solution and merely an addition to a previous answer, please edit your answer instead of making a new one.